# Issue of installing google-colab in jupyter env

Tags: pip, google-colaboratory, setuptools

I'm trying to install google-colab in my jupyter-lab.

`pip install google-colab`

but, error retuned like below.

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
  Running setup.py clean for pandas
  Building wheel for portpicker (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for portpicker: filename=portpicker-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl size=13385 sha256=0114e82fe25d308c42de106122212a10cc59c3523b646e0b6eee8aa04f0bd19d
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-mwy2mtxw/wheels/4e/19/2c/b772a272d0977b112ee6559cf6ce2390fb68b670940847770f
  Building wheel for tornado (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for tornado: filename=tornado-4.5.3-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl size=428025 sha256=845a96b82b0e89cb93061808e4d441e5eab09ea0c42460b8b15961cfca2c471f
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-mwy2mtxw/wheels/7a/fc/0f/8294151792cdc6cd7041df1467dbb536b4cff20d161d58501c
  Building wheel for simplegeneric (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for simplegeneric: filename=simplegeneric-0.8.1-py3-none-any.whl size=5076 sha256=3c9362702212300a478365b354a889036ffaa7b736f1c1f7116c67af9de3a5b0
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-mwy2mtxw/wheels/6a/88/e8/d4f4d830f0edaf91815bd9714e65b3c57ebc95c4ddfc6416a6
Successfully built google-colab portpicker tornado simplegeneric
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

probably, this is related to version or something, but I can't possibly figure it out. please tell me how to fix it.

version

setuptools 58.2.0

pip 23.2.1

I change the version of setuptools 58.2.0